# Kie trovi grupojn de Esperantistaj programistoj?

Tags: esperanto-speakers

Ĉu ekzistas grupoj de programistoj, kiuj kunlaboras pri komunaj projektoj uzante la lingvon Esperanto? Kie eblas trovi ilin, kaj alliĝi al ili?

Comment: Eble ni povas krei tian grupon, sed mi ne havas ideojn kiel kaj kie… :)

Answer (score 10):

Jam estas la jenaj grupoj:

- [Libera Programaro](https://plus.google.com/communities/108357154100435374012)
- [Tradukado de liberaj programaroj al Esperanto](https://www.facebook.com/groups/230428597153281/)
- [Komputiloj kaj Esperanto](https://www.facebook.com/groups/esperanto.informatiko/)
- [Esperanto per poŝtelefono](https://www.facebook.com/groups/641115069255313/)
- [Androidanoj - Esperanto por Android](https://www.facebook.com/groups/androidanaro/)
- [Linukso en Esperanto - Linux](https://www.facebook.com/groups/linukso/)
- [Esperanto-skipo de Ubuntu](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ubuntu.eo/)

Mi trovis la Fejsbukajn grupojn [ĉi tie](https://www.facebook.com/notes/esperanto/grupoj-de-fejsbuko-forumoj-en-esperanto/10150739764235289).

Comment: Oni bezonas konto kun Fejsbuko por sekvi ligiloj :(

Comment: Jes, bedaŭrinde. La [liston](https://www.facebook.com/notes/esperanto/grupoj-de-fejsbuko-forumoj-en-esperanto/10150739764235289) oni povas vidi sen konto.

Answer (score 7):

Ĉi-**Github** ekzistas [Esperanto organizo](https://github.com/Esperanto), Ĝi havas multajn membrojn kaj projektojn

Comment: Interesega, sed kiel ĉu vi aniĝas ĝin?

Comment: Kontaktu Georg => https://github.com/georgjaehnig